# How can I find repeated string segments in Python?

Tags: python, string, nlp

So I have some medium-length string - somewhere between a few words and a few sentences. Sometimes, a substring in the text is repeated twice in a row. I need to write automatic code to identify the repeated part. Or at least flag it with a high probability.

What I know:

1. The repeated substring is a series of a few whole words (and punctuation marks). A repeat will not happen in the middle of a word.
2. The repeat is of a variable length. It can be a few words to a few sentences itself. But it's always at least a few words long. I would like to avoid flagging single word repetitions if possible.
3. When a repeat happens, it's always repeated exactly once, and right after the previous appearence. right after the previous appearence. (<- example)
4. I need to run this check on about a million different strings, so the code has to be somewhat efficient at least (not the brute force check-every-option approach).

I've been struggling with this for a while now. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What you show so far is that you are interested in words or word sequences. Not just repe**titi**ve letter combinations. So I'd try to solve the problem using regular expression search.

Comment: ...but if you search for words, you may stumble upon repetitions of short words like *a* and *the*.

Comment: @Wolf Yes I will edit my question to make it clearer, thank you! And I know I'm not searching for single word repetiitons, like I wrote in (1)

Comment: (2) now, after my recent edit

Comment: This is not an easy task.  You're looking at brute force searching.  For each word, does this word appear again at N+1 or N+2 or N+3 or N+4, etc?  And if it does (for example) appear at N+4, then does N+1 == N+5 and N+2 == N+6 and N+3 == N+7?

Comment: I think that you should be more precise about the text length. If you are working on checking an email for copy-paste errors, an approach with one single regex (see my answer) may be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the repetition of *one word* is a **subclass** of a *multiple-word* repetition, it's already helpful to match single words or word-like sequences. Here is the regular expression I tried on your question in an [editor with regex search](https://notepad-plus-plus.org):

```
(\<\w.{3,16}\w\>).{2,}\1
```

This is the first repetition found

> The repeat is of a variable length. It can be **a few words to a few sentences itself. But it's always at least a few words** long. I would like to avoid flagging single word repetitions if possible.

But it next finds `repeat` in `repeating`. So we have to tune the limits.

The part `(\<\w.{3,16}\w\>)` means

- from word start (including a character)
- 3 to 16 arbitrary characters
- before word end (including a character)

In other words, one or more word with a total character count of 5 to 18.

The part `.{2,}\1` means

- at least two characters
- no upper limit
- captured match

Here, the lower limit can be higher. An upper limit *should* be tried, especially on longer text.

I'd think that starting with finding short character sequences which repeat, then refine by looking for longer sequences that repeat in the result of the first step (plus additional characters at the end).

It's also a matter of *preprocessing*. I'd guess that repeating multiple-word sequences should be missed if line breaks (instead of space occur) on different places.

To automate this further, you may switch to [Python's `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't really know anything about backreferencing in regex, so this really helped!